# Calculate Data Storage for a database in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake database storage includes (maybe there are some others)

- tables
- time travel
- fail safe
- clones
- files staged

I am trying to find a way to calculate tables + time-travel + fail-safe with and without clones **not** using TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS.

Currently looking at ACCOUNT_USAGE.database_storage_usage_history, but I am not sure what is included in AVERAGE_DATABASE_BYTES.

How do I find the correct values for current database?

Edit:

- I am not an account admin
- Would like to use query instead of UI

Edit 2: Result from SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS;
With no IMPORTED privilege or permission to view SNOWFLAKE database.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a great source of information on this:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/database_storage_usage_history.html#database-storage-usage-history-view

> Number of bytes of database storage used, including data in Time
> Travel.

Per your list, this would include tables, clones (which are tables on their own), and Time Travel.

For stages, you'd need to use the STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY view.

Is there a reason you don't want to use the TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS?  Just curious.

Comment: Do you know if AVERAGE_DATABASE_BYTES contains Fail-Safe or not? It looks like it is not from the description, but I want to be sure.
The result I got from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS somehow contains all NULL for TABLE_NAME and TABLE_CATALOG and the values change with role. Not quite sure what is happening there.

Comment: Our guess is TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS contains all tables that the role is able to access?

Comment: @BenaH It does not include fail safe, as there is another field for that.  And you guessed incorrectly regarding TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS.  In acccount_usage, you will see everything regardless of what your role has access to, as long as you've been granted permissions to the SNOWFLAKE share.  TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS likely has better data for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I think AVERAGE_DATABASE_BYTES + AVERAGE_FAILSAFE_BYTES + STAGE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY.AVERAGE_STAGE_BYTES is the formula I am looking for then. Please see Edit 2 above for my TABLE_STROAGE_METRICS output. Since I have no permission, I am not sure where these NULL are coming from.

Comment: TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS exists in ACCOUNT_USAGE, as well.  Don't use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view.  The TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS in ACCOUNT_USAGE will show you everything.

Comment: @ Mike Walton Thanks! This is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If you are an accout admin, you should be able to see this on your snowflake console

[image]

Comment: I am not an account admin, but I have monitor privilege. Any idea on the query that I can get what I want precisely?